# How to bind two xaml and xaml.cs files to one ViewModel using xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was wondering whether there is a way I could bind two xaml files to one viewmodel in order to allow data binding from one viewmodel to two xaml files.

Comment: Sure, just assign both pages BindingContext the same instance of the VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really easy actually,

```
SomePage somePage = new SomePage(); //View 1 
SomeOtherPage otherPage= new SomeOtherPage();  // View 2
YourCommonViewModel commonVm = new YourCommonViewModel(); //Common VM

somePage.BindingContext = commonVm;
otherPage.BindingContext= commonVm;
```

Hope this helps